# Passing javascript variable to spring MVC controller with request param

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is it possible to send a javascript variable to a controller endpoint, and then have the controller return a new view?
I've tried using a requestbody and ajax to do it, which passes the variable correctly, but is unable to load a new view.

Maybe there's a way to do it with thymeleaf?

Comment: @RequestParam can be used to pass values.May be you can share some more info and some code to have better understanding of the problem you are facing.

Comment: I have a controller method that I wish to pass a variable from a javascript function.
```
@GetMapping("/project/task")
    public String test(@RequestParam long id) {
        // create model from task id that goes to new view page
        return "taskpage";
    }
```
The javascript function retrieves the variable (task id), when clicking on a task (gantt diagram from google charts api).
```
$.ajax({
   contentType: "application/json",
   type: "GET",
   data: taskId
   url: "/project/task/"+id,
   });
 }
```
It doesnt work without requestbody (which doesnt load the new page)

Comment: From Javascript you are passing id in the url. So you can use @PathVariable to get it in controller. @GetMapping(“project/task/{id}”) public String test(@PathVariable Long id)

Comment: @Cozimetzer
That almost works, except it still won't load the new html page, but stays on the same page.. hmm..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Thymeleaf then just reference the template you want to return to the user by its filename.

```
@Controller
public class YourController {

    @GetMapping("/someUrl")
    public String getTemplate(@RequestParam String templateName){
        return templateName;
    }
}
```

This would be the bare minimum that you'd need, assuming your templates are in the correct folder - by default in `resources/static`. If the frontend sends a `GET (/someUrl?templateName=xyz)` to the backend, it would return the `xyz.html` from your templates. If it does not find the template that was requested in the parameters then it will return a 404.

Edit: Reading through the comments I realized there might be a confusion between `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`. In case you want to use a path variable to define the template name, so that the frontend can call `GET (/someUrl/xyz)`, then you can do

```
@Controller
public class YourController {

    @GetMapping("/someUrl/{templateName}")
    public String getTemplate(@PathVariable String templateName){
        return templateName;
    }
}
```

Resources for both below:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable